# ASP.NET MVC 5 Get Method with multiple forms persist search url query

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I have two forms within a single razor view that calls the same controller action.

If i filter the search results by a search input, the url persists the query param and value e.g **?SearmTerm=Value** which works fine.

However if I want to drill down with additional filters e.g. I select an option from a dropdown list and click on a search button that is wrapped in another form the **?SearmTerm=Value** is removed and a new query param is added **CategoryId=12**.

I know that if i use a single form, the search params and filters do persist within the url query string. Is it possible to do this with multiple forms ? I would like it to work like [http://www.carsales.com.au/](http://www.carsales.com.au/cars/results?sortby=TopDeal&limit=12&q=%28%28%28Make%3D%5BMazda%5D%26Model%3D%5BCX-7%5D%29%26Postcode%3Dpoi%5B2218x25km%5D%29%26Odometer%3Drange%5B20000..%5D%29) where you can add as many filters you like with a search button and the query url string persists with all the parameters and it's values.

Please see code that i currently have.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div id="filterAccordion" class="body" aria-multiselectable="true">
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="title" role="tab" id="Location">
            Category
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-icon="filterIcon" data-parent="#filterAccordion" href="#filterCollapseOne" aria-controls="filterCollapseOne">
                <span class="icon icon-keyboard_arrow_down"></span>
            </a>
        </div>
        <div id="filterCollapseOne" class="collapse content" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="Location">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directory", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryId, @Model.DirectoryCategories, "Select Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "custom-select form control" })

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn search-btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
                </div>                      
            }
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
<div class="search-bar">
@using (@Html.BeginForm("Index", "Directory", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBoxFor(d => d.SearchTerm, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = "Search Directory"})
    <button type="submit" class="search-btn"></button>
}
</div>
```

**View Model**

```
public class DirectoryIndexViewModel
{
   public List<Models.Directory> ActiveDirectories { get; set; }
   public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DirectoryCategories { get; set; }
   public string SearchTerm { get; set; }
   public string SortBy { get; set; }
   public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

**DirectoryController**

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index(DirectoryIndexViewModel model)
{
  var query = _directoryRepository.GetAllActiveDirectories();
  var categories =    _selectListService.GetDirectoryCategories(model.CategoryId);

  var searchTerm = model.SearchTerm;

  if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(searchTerm))
  {
      query = query.Where(d => d.Name.ToUpper().Contains(searchTerm.ToUpper()));
  }

  query = query.OrderByDescending(d => d.IsFeatured);

  return View(new DirectoryIndexViewModel
  {
      ActiveDirectories = query.ToList(),
      DirectoryCategories = categories == null ? null : categories,
      SearchTerm = searchTerm,
      CategoryId = model.CategoryId
  });
}
```

Comment: Why 2 forms instead of a single form? (the site you linked to has only a single form).

Comment: Hi @StephenMuecke i have updated the link which goes to the results page where you can drill down. Also the reason why i wan't to use multiple forms within a single view so i can keep the view page tidy then wrapping everything to one form.

Comment: Not sure why you think multiple forms make it 'tidy'. You can only ever submit one form at a time so it makes no sense. But you can always use javascript to intercept the `.submit()` events, cancel it and build your own url based on the controls and use `location.href = yourUrl;` to redirect.

Comment: Thanks for the info @StephenMuecke. I've also noticed that carsales website seem to hold the query params and it's values in an custom html-5 attribute called 'data-placeholder' within most of their search filters.